# Why is there no std::transform_n function in the C++ standard library?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

I can find no mention of a transform_n function in draft [N4431](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf) of the C++ standard.

Is this intentional?  If not, how would one go about suggesting this for a future version of the standard?

Here is how I would implement it:

```
    template<typename _InputIterator, typename Size, typename _OutputIterator, typename _UnaryOperation>
_OutputIterator transform_n(_InputIterator __first, Size __n, _OutputIterator __result, _UnaryOperation __op) {
    for(Size i=0;i<__n;++i)
        *__result++ = __op(*__first++);
    return __result;
}


template<typename _InputIterator1, typename Size, typename _InputIterator2, typename _OutputIterator, typename _BinaryOperation>
_OutputIterator transform_n(_InputIterator1 __first1, Size __n, _InputIterator2 __first2, _OutputIterator __result, _BinaryOperation __binary_op) {
    for(Size i=0;i<__n;++i)
        *__result++ = __binary_op(*__first1++, *__first2++);
    return __result;
}
```

Comment: See https://isocpp.org/std/submit-a-proposal. Be sure to come up with some compelling use cases.

Comment: @TonyD: it's not just that it saves you an advance, since you can't pass through the same input iterator twice. But you could use `std::generate_n` with a lambda.

Comment: I would be more interested in encoding this in the iterators (or ranges) themselves, rather than having a `_n` version for every algorithm. For example, Eric Niebler's [range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), which has the `take(N)` adaptor which takes the first N elements of a range.

Comment: @rici: `std::generate_n` has mandatory in-order invocations of the generator, whereas `std::transform` can happen in any order, so a `generate_n` approach might be at a performance cost in some situations.

Comment: @rici although `generate_n` uses a generator, so you'd have to capture the original range's iterators in the generator.

Comment: @vsoftco: sure, but by reference.

Comment: @rici does it make a difference? Capturing by value should be fine, as iterators are "thin" objects.

Comment: @vsoftco: By my comment I meant that it's not a big deal. Lambdas have captures.

Comment: @TonyD: the only case where you could plausibly have a performance benefit is one in which std::advance has no cost; the only plausible use case for the proposed transform_n is where it is impossible to compute the iterator for the end of the range because the start of the range is an input iterator. Although I'm not convinced that is a good use case, either.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another possible implementation, which shows that there is already a library function with equivalent functionality:

```
template<typename _InputIterator,
         typename _OutputIterator,
         typename _UnaryOperation>
_OutputIterator transform_n(_InputIterator __first,
                            size_t __n,
                            _OutputIterator __result,
                            _UnaryOperation __op) {
      return std::generate_n(__result, __n,
                             [&__first, &__op]() -> decltype(auto) {
                                return __op(*__first++);
                             });
}
```

As @TonyD mentions in a comment, this has the effect of forcing the transformation to happen in order, but that would already be the case if the input iterator argument is really just an input iterator.

Edit: As per the suggestion by @T.C., I changed the lambda to have a return type of `decltype(auto)`, which (if I understand correctly) could allow move semantics through the output iterator. That requires a recent compiler, since it's a C++14 feature.

Comment: The lambda should return `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: @T.C.: OK. I also made it (correctly, I think) pass through the return value from generate_n.

Comment: The point of `decltype(auto)` is to make the lambda return exactly what the call to `__op` returns. If the call returns a reference to something, you don't want to make a copy - said something might not even be copyable! The C++11 equivalent is `-> decltype(/* the expression returned */)`. TBH, getting the lambda right is sufficiently tricky that I can see an argument for a library solution.