# Best practice about for loop with an const if inside in cpp

Tags: c++, performance

For example.

```cpp
  if (bitwidth == 0) {
    for (int bhwc = 0; bhwc < B * H * W * C; ++bhwc) {
      p_res[bhwc] = res_f32[bhwc];
    }
  } else {
    for (int bhwc = 0; bhwc < B * H * W * C; ++bhwc) {
      p_res[bhwc] = res_f32[bhwc].toint(bitwidth, fracwidth);
    }
  }
```

vs

```cpp
  for (int bhwc = 0; bhwc < B * H * W * C; ++bhwc) {
    if (bitwidth == 0) {
      p_res[bhwc] = res_f32[bhwc];
    } else {
      p_res[bhwc] = res_f32[bhwc].toint(bitwidth, fracwidth);
    }
  }
```

The second one is more readable and maintainable, but it's maybe slower. Is there any better method?(As you can see, The outside for loop may be very complex, with 4 dimension...

Comment: "maybe slower" is not something you should worry about, "readability" on the other hand matters always. If you really care about performance you must measure

Comment: Compiler is probably smart enaough do do that. Try your example on godbolt.org and look at the assembly. For my little example gcc was smart enough

Answer (score 3):

The performance implications are insignificant, and every modern compiler should be able to optimize that to avoid the branch in the middle of the loop.

However, this shows an interesting problem, and serves as a great argument against using `for` loops. They're a very low-level construct and should be avoided where the alternatives can be applied. In this case, using them forces you to choose between a clean-looking implementation (with potential performance drawback) and a technically-better one, but stylistically suboptimal.

Your two operations can be described in terms of two generic operations: `copy` and `transform`. You can write the algorithm in terms of them, like so:

```
if (bitwidth == 0) {
    using std::copy_n;
    copy_n(res_f32, B * H * W * C, p_res);
} else {
    transform_n(res_f32, B * H * W * C, p_res, [=](auto const& x){ return x.toint(bitwidth, fracwidth); });
}
```

Unfortunately, there's no `std::transform_n`, but [you can make one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30496977/752976). Alternatively, and much better, if your `B*H*W*C` term can be stored in terms of the container, it'd be best to express that as a view or the container's `begin/end` directly, thus enabling the use of the automatic (non-`_n`) `copy/transform` instead.

This is not just more readable, but expresses the logic in the commonly-understood terms of standard operations, leaves less room for errors and allows much easier changes of underlying containers, operations, potential parallelism and overall maintainability.